# How to use the pandas Series.interpolate to insert data into NAN

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data, some of them have Nan. The problem is I can't insert data into Nan when it is at top or bottom area by using pandas.Series.interpolate, even by method od fillna.
I want to know if there is any better to replace NAN by the proper data?
Here is the problem as below shown by photo:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIxHY.png)

Comment: Please consider revising the code sample you posted in this question. Posting code as images is discouraged. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `limit_direction` to `"both"`.

Demo data

```
data = pd.Series([None,1,None,5,None])
print(data)

0    NaN
1    1.0
2    NaN
3    5.0
4    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Result

```
data.interpolate(limit_direction="both")

0    1.0
1    1.0
2    3.0
3    5.0
4    5.0
dtype: float64
```